# Azure Automation Runbook - Randomly occurring error: Resource group '{resource-group-name}' could not be found

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

We keep randomly getting the error "Resource group '{resource-group-name}' could not be found" when running our runbooks, where {resource-group-name} is the name of one of our resource groups. These runbooks are either running in that resource group, or have selected the subscription where that resource group resides. The RunAs account also has Contributor permissions on the resource group(s). This is happening in runbooks that we run daily. Sometimes we get the error and sometimes we don't. There doesn't appear to be a reason for this happening. It's almost like the Azure runbook worker is losing context. We are not using a hybrid runbook worker. We've tried a number of things, including ensuring that our RunAs connection is logged in to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try below way of connection:

```
Disable-AzContextAutosave –Scope Process
$connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection

$logonAttempt = 0
while(!($connectionResult) -And ($logonAttempt -le 10))
{
$LogonAttempt++
# Logging in to Azure...
$connectionResult = Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $connection.TenantID -ApplicationID $connection.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $connection.CertificateThumbprint
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
}
$AzureContext = Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $connection.SubscriptionID
Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -AzureRmContext $AzureContext
```

As shown below, I got the same error code ResourceGroupNotFound when I have provided a dummy non-existing resource group name so I suggest you to double check the resource group name part i.e., may be some extra whitespace is getting added to your actual resource group name or something of that sort might be the reason for your issue.

[image]

Comment: we haven't tried the retry logic while connecting. Is there any reason to expect that it fails to connect fairly often? We've done everything else you shared in your sample code including Disable-AzContextAutosave, I've also confirmed that the Resource Group does not have extra whitespace.

Comment: In general retry logic is suggested in situations like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/troubleshoot/runbooks#resolution-1). If this didn’t help, after Select-AzSubscription line check if expected output is generated or not by using [Get-AzContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azcontext?view=azps-3.8.0). If yes, use [Get-AzResourceGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourcegroup?view=azps-3.8.0) along with your RG name.

Comment: If above [Get-AzResourceGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourcegroup?view=azps-3.8.0) along with your RG name line gives output stating it’s able to find the required RG and then if Get-AzVM line fails with RG not found error then as suggested [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/53397), please open a support ticket.

Comment: We are still getting the errors after implementing the retry logic. I will be opening a ticket today.

Comment: no point of looping connection since it is not the actual root cause for above question.